# Problems enabling SessionState in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-state

My attempts at enabling SessionState are failing :-(

I've added the following page directive to the page:

```
<%@ Page ... EnableSessionState="True" %>
```

And to my web.config file, I've added the following:

```
<system.web>
...
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />

    <pages enableSessionState="true">
        ...
    </pages>
    <remove name="session" />
    <add name="session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
...
</system.web>
```

As far as I believe, this should work and I should be able to access the Session object in my code - I'm getting an HTTPException advising me to make sure the above is in my web.config file.

The following line:

```
<remove name="session" />
```

was added because without it I get the following error:

The entry 'session' has already been added.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
<system.web>
...
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />
...
</system.web>
```

Remove the rest from the page and the web.config and it should work. Session is enabled by default.

Comment: Now I'm getting 

"The entry 'session' has already been added." as an error.

Comment: you must have other settings which are conflicting.  has your machine.config been modified?  if you create a new test web app, does session work in that one?